# Converting code from Objective-C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, url, instagram

I'm developing a new app in Swift and I want to hook up Instagram to my app. I found the iPhone hook up for Instagram but it's in objective C.

Can anyone help me in converting it to swift?

Here is the code:

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://location?id=1"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to do in swift like as follows

```
    var instagramURL : NSURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://location?id=1")!
    if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(instagramURL)) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(instagramURL)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 4.2

```
let instagramURL = URL(string: "instagram://location?id=1")
if let anURL = instagramURL {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(anURL) {
         UIApplication.shared.openURL(anURL)
    }
}
```

Converted to Swift using [Swiftify.me](http://swiftify.me/fqdgtx)